# Develop function to find all permutations of a sequence of digits

Tags: javascript

I need to write a JavaScript function that shows me all the permutations of the digits of the number passed as an argument, but not sure how to do it.

For example, given 1020, it would produce

1020 , 0120 , 0210 , 0102.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var result = [];
var newArray = [];

    function permute(someArray) {
        var i, ch;
        for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
            ch = someArray.splice(i, 1)[0];
            newArray.push(ch);
            if (someArray.length == 0) {
                result.push(newArray.slice());
            }
            permute(someArray);
            someArray.splice(i, 0, ch);
            newArray.pop();
        }

        return result;
    };

    var n =  1901;
    var arr = (""+n).split("");

    var myResult = permute(arr);

    for(var i in myResult){
        console.log(myResult[i].join(""));
    }
```

Comment: Tested it in node.js interpreter, worked perfectly. Output: 1901
1910
1091
1019
1190
1109
9101
9110
9011
9011
9110
9101
0191
0119
0911
0911
0119
0191
1190
1109
1910
1901
1019
1091

Comment: @clearlight glad it works :)

Comment: @HeryDev, Why result.push(newArray.slice()), and not just result.push(newArray)?